# Firestore Query Date Range

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, querying

I have a date range on my documents (using date objects) something like this

```
{
  start: March 5
  end: April 7
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would build a query to return all events which cover a specific day, for example `March 27`, so like....

A query that says something like `get all documents whose starting date is before march 27th, and the ending date is after march 27th` but it looks like this may not be possible with the Firestore query limitations.

So I have been scratching my head for hours to either build a query for this, or structure my data in some way which would allow this.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible in Firestore but please add a screenshot of your real database.

Answer (score 1):

From the code above saves my day. I know this structure of code is odd but it works.
This can be use to search date range, I hope it helps!

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Manila"));
    Date newDate = null;
    Date newDate1 = null;
    try {
        newDate = sdf.parse(YOUR_EDIT_TEXT + " 00:00:00");
        newDate1 = sdf.parse(YOUR_EDIT_TEXT + " 23:59:59");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    db.collection("sales")
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("created_at", newDate)
            .whereLessThan("created_at", newDate1)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    for(final DocumentSnapshot sales: task.getResult()) {
                        // Do what ever you want with the data.
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, please, comment it a little bit. In this case, there is another answer so you should expose the Pros of your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use less than and greater that query. For example in my android for snapshot listener (listening updates) app I've done something like this:

```
    ListenerRegistration registration;
    String lessDate = "09/04/2019 23:59:59";
    String greaterDate = "11/04/2019 23:59:59";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date lDate = dateFormat.parse(lessDate);
        Date gDate = dateFormat.parse(greaterDate);
        Query q = db.collection("collection").whereGreaterThan("createdAt", new Timestamp(lDate))
                .whereLessThan("createdAt", new Timestamp(gDate));
        registration = q.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.i("FIRESTORE ERROR", "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }
                for (DocumentChange doc : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    // What ever you want to do.
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For dates, you can actually get a date from the system or take input from the user and customize it according to your need. Let me know if you need any help.