# [Resolved ]how to convert date format dd/mm/yyyy to firestore timestamp format in order to send a query based on date given?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need help to convert my date given dd/MM/yyyy to firestore timestamp format in order to be able to send a firestore query to fetch all row from collection

Date to send is dd/MM/yyyy "24/05/2022"
firestore date
[image]

Firestore query :

```
  fStore.collection("data").whereEqualTo("ID", userId).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date", "24/05/2022").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {}
```

I am expected to get one row only as i have only one row of data which date is May 25,2022

Comment: You really don't want to store your dates as strings like that.  That will just cause other problems later because they won't sort chronologically.  Instead, consider just building a timestamp the represents the point in time where you would like to start your query and pass that.

Comment: Are you asking [how to parse a date from a string in Java?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+parse+a+date+from+a+string+in+Java)

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson but i need to filter my data based on month , for example i want to fetch all data row for May so i want to send a query date is greater than or equal to 01/05/2022

Comment: no @FrankvanPuffelen ,i need to filter my data based on date given (24/05/2022) but in firestore date format is different, not sure how to handle it

Comment: You should convert that date string to a Date or Timestamp first.  That's what Frank is pointing to.

Comment: Is there any resource or example which i can refer ?pls .I have been trying and ending in loop with no luck

Comment: You can pass a `Date` object to Firestore. --- Also: if you've tried to parse the date yourself already, edit your question to show what you tried and what problem/error you got after that.

Comment: Thanks ,I have resolved the issue by following same question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348853/firestore-query-date-range

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Query Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348853/firestore-query-date-range)